# fixed elements move on WKWebkit

Tags: javascript, ios, css, native, wkwebview

Native app consists of WkWebview and blue native nav bar.

Running this on an iPad with iOS 10.3.1 with Safari 10

Bounce is enabled.

WkWebview shows a position:fixed brown overlay and a modal on top.

As shown in [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrNcr.jpg), the fixed overlay is moveable. The body content under the fixed overlay moves behind the overlay.

Is there any way to prevent the move of the fixed overlay?

Comment: can you post a fiddle or explain better what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: added a video so show the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is solved on Safari in iOS 11.